# Como fazer MapPath Asp clássico

Tags: asp

Como fazer MapPath Asp clássico, uso barra normal "/" ou invertida "\", posso utilizar métodos e variáveis para incluir no endereço do objeto?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Problema com MapPath Asp clássico](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/68922/problema-com-mappath-asp-cl%c3%a1ssico)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<%
' Para ajudar desmembre seu código pois fica fácil verificar o que está dando errado.

'@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ ANTES
ind = ind & "<span><b><a href='"&vStrParametro7&"/Busca/"&rsQuery("ID_CURSO")&"/"&Server.UrlEncode(TirarAcento(rsQuery("DESCR")))&"' target='blank'>"&rsQuery("SIGLA")&" - "&rsQuery("DESCR")&"</a></b><span>"
if fso.FileExists(Server.MapPath("/" & Application("pathAdm") & "/" &vStrParametro6& "/cursos/" & vStrPDF2(z))) then
    objCDOSYSMail.AddAttachment(Server.MapPath("/" & Application("pathAdm") & "/" &vStrParametro6& "/cursos/" & vStrPDF2(z)))
end if
'@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ ANTES - FIM 

'@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ DEPOIS - Melhor tratado para debugar e saber o que está ocorrendo
'Declaro as variáveis assim posso utilizá-las em todo o restante do código de forma mais curta e irá facilitar meu debug manual
Dim cursoID         : cursoID = rsQuery("ID_CURSO")
Dim SIGLA           : SIGLA = rsQuery("SIGLA")
Dim DESCR           : DESCR = rsQuery("DESCR")
Dim DESCR_TRATADO   : DESCR_TRATADO = Server.UrlEncode(TirarAcento(DESCR))
Dim url             : url = vStrParametro7 & "/Busca/" & cursoID & "/" & DESCR_TRATADO
Dim pathAdm         : pathAdm = Application("pathAdm")
Dim vStrPDF2        : vStrPDF2 = vStrPDF2(z)
Dim Endereco        : Endereco = Server.MapPath( "/" & pathAdm & "/" & vStrParametro6 & "/cursos/" & vStrPDF2 )
Dim sHTML           : sHTML = "<span><b><a href='"& url &"' target='blank'>"& SIGLA &" - "& DESCR &"</a></b><span>"

'@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ DEBUG MANUAL PARA SABER EXATAMENTE O QUE CADA VARIÁVEL ESTÁ RECEBENDO PARA SER TRATADO
'@@ para utilizar o debug, basta descomentar o item necessário e o último response.end(), ou descomente todos
' Dica: Já deixei descomentado para você analisar uns itens, porém creio ser melhor depois você analisar um a um dos objetos ok

response.write "<hr><br><br>"
'response.write "cursoID: " & cursoID & "<br>"
'response.write "SIGLA: " & SIGLA & "<br>"
'response.write "DESCR: " & DESCR & "<br>"
'response.write "DESCR_TRATADO: " & DESCR_TRATADO & "<br>"
'response.write "url: " & url & "<br>"
response.write "pathAdm: " & pathAdm & "<br>"
response.write "vStrParametro6: " & vStrParametro6 & "<br>"
response.write "vStrPDF2: " & vStrPDF2 & "<br>"
response.write "Endereco: " & Endereco & "<br>"
'response.write "sHTML: " & sHTML & "<br>"
response.write "<br><hr>"
response.end()

'Obs Application() deve estar sendo utilizado no arquivo Global.asa para ser utilizado em páginas *.asp
'Referência http://www.w3schools.com/asp/asp_applications.asp

ind = ind & sHTML

if fso.FileExists(Endereco) then
    objCDOSYSMail.AddAttachment(Endereco)
end if

'@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ DEPOIS - FIM

'Segue um exemplo de como utilizar o Server.MapPath(path)
response.write(Server.MapPath("test.asp") & "<br>")
response.write(Server.MapPath("script/test.asp") & "<br>")
response.write(Server.MapPath("/script/test.asp") & "<br>")
response.write(Server.MapPath("\script") & "<br>")
response.write(Server.MapPath("/") & "<br>")
response.write(Server.MapPath("\") & "<br>")

'Saída:
'c:\inetpub\wwwroot\script\test.asp
'c:\inetpub\wwwroot\script\script\test.asp
'c:\inetpub\wwwroot\script\test.asp
'c:\inetpub\wwwroot\script
'c:\inetpub\wwwroot
'c:\inetpub\wwwroot

'Referência: http://www.w3schools.com/asp/met_mappath.asp
%>
```

Comment: O que faz esse código?

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar o mappath atribuindo o seu valor a uma variavel, ou até mesmo dentro do objeto.

A forma das barras depende, já precisei alterar elas para funcionar com os componentes.

Ex:
Posso usar diretamente com o objeto.

```
Set fs1=Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
if fs1.FileExists(Server.MapPath("\admin\minha_foto.jpg")) then
    fs1.DeleteFile(Server.MapPath("\admin\minha_foto.jpg"))
end if
```

ou atribuir a uma variavel e utiliza-la:

```
foto=Server.MapPath("\admin\minha_foto.jpg")
Set fs1=Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
if fs1.FileExists(foto) then
    fs1.DeleteFile(foto))
end if
```

Depende da sua aplicação.

Answer (score -1):

Eu faço assim:

```
endereco = Server.MapPath("./") & "\banco.mdb"
```